# How can I delete appointment from my calendar but not cancel meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, appointments

I have created many appointments for my team, so I am the originator and the only one who can make changes to the appointment.  I am leaving this team and would like to remove these appointments from my calendar, but **not** delete/cancel the meeting for other participants.

How, as the appointment originator, can I delete for just myself?

Comment: "How, as the appointment originator, can I delete for just myself?" - You can't; If you delete the series, as the originator, it's deleted from everyone's calendar that accepted the invited. My suggestion is whomever will be leading the team, replace those invites, with their own calendar entry. An alternative solution is to use a common account instead, this way when an individual leaves, they don't have to worry about the account being deleted.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps:

1.Open the meeting in your calendar, and click **Cancle Meeting**.
[image]

2.Then put this cancellation email aside for the time being and switch to the Calendar View. Click **Send/Receive**>Click **Work Offline**.

[image]

3.Then go back to the cancellation email and click **Send Cancellation**.

[image]

4.At this time, the cancellation email will stay in the Outbox, we just need to find the unsent cancellation email in the Outbox and delete it.

5.Then on the **Send/Receive** tab, remember to click **Work Offline** again to get online.

In this way, the meeting will only be deleted in your calendar but not in the calendars of other attendees.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.