# Can I delete organization event from my calendar without affecting their event?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have found an event in my Outlook calendar as in the attachment (I omitted the details of the event). I will not attend this event. Is it safe to delete it from my calendar or will this operation delete the event for all people?

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get the event in your calender, as an invite has been sent to you and others. When you click the event and press delete, outlook will show you a popup, asking you if you want to only delete the appointment from your calender, or send a delete request to everyone.

If you click the button to only delete from your calender, it will just be removed from yours.

If you click the button to delete from everyone's calender, you will send a delete request to the person who invited you, and if they approve, it will then send a delete request to everyone else, which should automatically remove the appointment from every mailbox.

Do note, if this appointment is in a shared mailbox, deleting the appointment will immediately delete it, no popup.

Given that your image shows the blue/white slanted line on the left, this means you got an invite, but never responded whether you will go or not. This is the status pending. This can only happen if you get invited, so this should also mean that this is in your own calender, not a shared calender.

Comment: your final statement means if I delete it, then it will be deleted only from my calendar, right?

Comment: If its on your own calendar for an invite, you get a popup, if you choose to delete only from your calender, then that is what will happen, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether the calendar event is organized by you.

**If this is meeting organized and you accept**, your deletion on your calendar won't affect the other person (other meeting participants or meeting organizers).

**If this is a meeting you organize**, of course there is a way to avoid influencing others. Please refer to my reply in this thread to cancel a meeting without sending a meeting cancellation email to other participants: [How can I delete appointment from my calendar but not cancel meeting?](https://superuser.com/questions/1747497/how-can-i-delete-appointment-from-my-calendar-but-not-cancel-meeting/1747865#1747865:%7E:text=Please%20try%20the%20following%20steps%3A)

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.